# Having a read only working table and a writable insertion table then switch which table the select query reads from

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization, large-data

Here is the scenario:

TableA - schema does not really matter
TableB - same schema as TableA

```
SYNONYM ROTable FROM TableA  

SYNONYM InsertTable from TableB  

select * from ROTable ... (read only)

Trunc InsertTable   
BULK insert into InsertTable () ... some data  
DROP SYNONYM ROTable   
DROP SYNONYM InsertTable  

SYNONYM ROTable FROM TableB  
SYNONYM InsertTable from TableA
```

I am not even sure what to call this technique, but I have always called it DOUBLE BUFFERED BULK INSERTS. You have 2 identical tables, you read from one, while you are inserting records into the second. Once you are done inserting records into the second, you switch to reading from the second table and truncate the first table and start your bulk inserts again.

This would be used for cases when you don't want to do UPSERTS on your active table when you have large amounts of UPSERTS to do.

The question is: Is this a viable technique, why or why not and does it have a common name?

Comment: Interesting question - it is a useful and frequently used pattern but does the general pattern have a name? If not you have first dibs - you should write a blog and call it the Michael Horn technuique :) Here's an article using a similar pattern but again the name is technique-specific (partitions) https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/ It is also effectively implemented with RCSI. Maybe it can be considered a type of concurrency model??

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a viable way to alternate two sets of tables in ETL and reporting.
In Oracle same can be achieved using partition exchanges.

Comment: Does it have a common name?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I would call it "interchangable synonyms"